# Center align the icon in a message box

Tags: css, html

I want to align the check or the icon such that it should come at the center horizontally and vertically and considering the height of the message box is auto.

```css
.done {
  position: relative;
  /* necessary for positioning the :after */
}

.done {
  list-style: none;
  /* remove normal bullet for done items */
}

.left-pop {
  float: left;
  width: 110px;
  height: auto;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.right-pop {
  float: right;
  width: 340px;
  height: auto;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  border-left: 2px solid rgba(60, 118, 61, 0.22);
}

.close-span {
  border-radius: 50%;
  float: right;
  padding: 0px 8px 3px 8px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  font-size: 19px;
  top: 5px;
  color: #f5f5f5;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.unsuccessclose-span {
  border-radius: 50%;
  float: right;
  padding: 0px 8px 3px 8px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  font-size: 19px;
  top: 5px;
  color: #f5f5f5;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.success-popup {
  width: 450px;
  height: auto;
  overflow: auto;
  background: rgba(27, 197, 163, 1);
  position: relative;
  margin: 80px;
}

.unsuccess-popup {
  width: 450px;
  height: auto;
  overflow: auto;
  background: rgba(244, 67, 54, 0.79);
  position: relative;
  margin: 80px;
}

.unsuccessright-pop {
  float: right;
  width: 340px;
  height: auto;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  border-left: 2px solid rgba(244, 67, 54, 0.69);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,100i,300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,700,700i,900,900i" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="success-popup">

  <span class="close-span">x</span>
  <div class="left-pop">
    <i class="fa fa-check" style="font-size:40px;color:white;display: block;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto"></i>
  </div>
  
  <div class="right-pop">
    <h4>Success!</h4>
    <p>You successfully read this important alert<br></p>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nish4114/kt2p7vbh/1/

Comment: Have you tried flexbox?

Comment: you could set the height of the left element and do it like this: https://jsfiddle.net/kt2p7vbh/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way will make anything within the div with the class `.success-popup` be centered.

```
.left-pop {
    width: 110px; 
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }

.success-popup {
    width: 450px;
    height: auto;
    overflow: auto;
    margin: 80px;
    background: rgba(27, 197, 163, 1);
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to align the tick in the centre using flex, I would also use that for your boxes (instead of floats) - I have removed all your floats from the below code and added comments next to any additions.

```css
.done {
  position: relative;
  /* necessary for positioning the :after */
  list-style: none;
  /* remove normal bullet for done items */
}

.left-pop {
  width: 110px;

  /* 
  height: auto;
  padding-top: 10px;   not sure what these are for so have removed them*/
  
  /* the following will align the tick */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;  /* vertical centring */
  align-items: center;      /* horizontal centring */
}

.right-pop {
  width: 340px;
  height: auto;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  border-left: 2px solid rgba(60, 118, 61, 0.22);
}

.close-span {
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 0px 8px 3px 8px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  font-size: 19px;
  top: 5px;
  color: #f5f5f5;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.unsuccessclose-span {
  border-radius: 50%;
  float: right;
  padding: 0px 8px 3px 8px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  font-size: 19px;
  top: 5px;
  color: #f5f5f5;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.success-popup {
  width: 450px;
  height: auto;
  overflow: auto;
  background: rgba(27, 197, 163, 1);
  position: relative;
  margin: 80px;
  
  display: flex;      /* add the following so you don't need to use floats and so the boxes become equal heights*/
}

.unsuccess-popup {
  width: 450px;
  height: auto;
  overflow: auto;
  background: rgba(244, 67, 54, 0.79);
  position: relative;
  margin: 80px;
}

.unsuccessright-pop {
  float: right;
  width: 340px;
  height: auto;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  border-left: 2px solid rgba(244, 67, 54, 0.69);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,100i,300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,700,700i,900,900i" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="success-popup">

  <span class="close-span">x</span>

  <div class="left-pop">

    <i class="fa fa-check" style="font-size:40px;color:white;display: block;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto"></i>

  </div>
  <div class="right-pop">
    <h4>Success!</h4>
    <p>You successfully read this impoortant alert<br></p>


  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest to make the entire module to use nested flexbox, see the simplified code below:

```css
.success-popup {
  width: 450px;
  display: flex;
  background: rgba(27, 197, 163, 1);
  color: #fff;
}

.left-pop {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 110px;
}

.left-pop .fa {
  font-size: 40px;
}

.right-pop {
  border-left: 2px solid rgba(60, 118, 61, 0.22);
  padding: 20px 10px;
  flex: 1;
}

.right-pop h4 {
  font-size: 18px;
  margin: 0 0 10px;
}

.right-pop p {
  margin: 0;
}

.close-span {
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="success-popup">
  <div class="left-pop">
    <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="right-pop">
    <h4>Success!</h4>
    <p>You successfully read this impoortant alert</p>
  </div>
  <span class="close-span">
    <i class="fa fa-close"></i>
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the icon style as

```
 <i class="fa fa-check" style="font-size:40px;color:white;display: table; margin: 0 auto;" ></i>
```